# Creating linkable images using Flexslider and Slideshow View

Tags: views, javascript

I am looking to create the ability to have my slider images link to link specified in my field_link. I have tried to put the node [field_link], but it is reading as plain text. I have tried a few suggestions, but I must not be doing them right.

Below you will find the current configuration I am using.

**This is how I have set up my Slideshow View:**
[image: This is how I have set up my Slideshow View]

**This is how I have set up my Image Field:**
[image]

**This is how I have set up my Link Field:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this the same way you are doing it.  Try putting (rearrange order) the field_link before/above the field_image in your view fields list.  Views reads through them one at a time.. and as you have it, field_link isn't yet available when it's processing the field_image.  does that make sense?

Comment: Do you leave link path blank?

Comment: no, you have everything in the right place, using the correct tokens. The only reason the link isn't available it seems, it because you have Field:link after Field:Image.  If you click 'Rewrite the output of this field' you can see a list of "available" tokens for each field as you move down you list. You may find it useful to see how Views handles this

Comment: I eventually found out that the replacement pattern I was using was slightly incorrect. Thanks so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have always had to modify the view template for the specific display to wrap everything in a link properly. The issue is compounded even more when using [Picture](https://drupal.org/project/picture) for responsive image variations.

The custom template changes aren't extensive, but I've not found a re-usable or GUI based method to do this with sliders.

Comment: Ok would you mind expanding on the template changes you have made?

Answer (score -1):

How do you get fields: ? I only have content and feeds etc. not fields.

I have a field collection with three fields:
1: field_slideshow_link
2: field_slideshow_image
3: field_slideshow_title

I want to link the image to the link provided in 1.

so I want to rewrite the output, "Output this field as a link" setting should be [field_slideshow_link]
How do I do that in a collection?

Comment: this is not the answer, create the new question for this...